# Number of ways to place 2 red, 2 blue, 1 yellow ball into two distinct boxes of capacity 2 and 3

Tags: combinatorics

The answer to this particular question is 5 (solved by brute force), but I am looking for a closed form expression or methodology for solving this type of problem, namely, given n distinct ball types of quantity $x_1,x_2, ..., x_n$, and given m distinct boxes of capacity/size $y_1, y_2, ..., y_m$ where $\sum x_i = \sum y_j$, how many possible placements are there (order within boxes does not matter)? I've so far been looking at the twelve- and twenty-fold way but it is the capacity restrictions I haven't encountered before (that go beyond exactly one, greater than 1, etc.), and I believe that also means you can't apply stars and bars because you can't assign the distinct balls independently. My last thought is this might involve the inclusion-exclusion principle to get the quantities you want but I don't know where to start with that.

Note: this came out of playing with some graph theory rather than a textbook, so while it seems generally solvable to me I'm hoping but uncertain if it can be coded succinctly into an algorithm.

Comment: Any general closed form would probably be messy even is it existed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use generating functions. It is the coefficient of $x^2$ in: $$(1+x+x^2)^2(1+x)=\frac{(1-x^3)(1-x^2)}{1-x)^3}$$

If there are $m_1$ red, $m_2$ blue and $m_3$ yellow and boxes of size $n$ and $m_1+m_2+m_3-n,$ then you are look for the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series:

$$f(x)=\frac{(1-x^{m_1+1})(1-x^{m_2+1})(1-x^{m_3+1})}{(1-x)^3}$$

Now $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+2}{2}x^k.$$

Then the coefficient of $x^n$ is:

$$\begin{align}&\binom{n+2}2\\&-\left(\binom{n+1-m_1}{2}+\binom{n+1-m_2}2+\binom{n+1-m_3}2\right)\\&+\left(\binom{n-m_1-m_2}2+\binom{n-m_1-m_3}2+\binom{n-m_2-m_3}2\right)\\
&-\binom{n-1-m_1-m_2-m_3}2
\end{align}$$

The last term is zero, since $n-1-m_1-m_2-m_3<0.$

When $n=2$ and $m_1=m_2=2,m_3=1,$ all the terms are zero other than:

$$\binom{n+2}{2}-\binom{n+1-m_3}{2}=5.$$

We should get the same value for $n=3$ and $m_1=m_2=2,m_3=1,$ and you do:

$$\binom{5}2-\binom22-\binom22-\binom32=5$$

There isn’t an easier formula. If there are $c$ colors, then there might be $2^c-1$ terms.

It gets down to $c+1$ terms if the $m_i$ are all equal.

It gets much more complicated when there are more than $2$ boxes. I’m not sure this approach even extends well to that case.

---

You can get the same formula using an inclusion-exclusion argument, rather than a generating function argument.

Let $$A=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\mid a_i\in \mathbb Z^{\geq0},a_1+a_2+a_3=n\}$$ and $$A_i=(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in A\mid a_i>m_i\}$$ then applying inclusion-exclusion to evaluate:

$$\left|A\setminus(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3)\right|$$

Answer (score 1):

Your generalized problem is equivalent to counting the number of $n\times m$ matrices with entries in $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$, such that row sums are $[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ ,and the columns sums are $[y_1,\dots,y_m]$. The following is a survey of known results related to this problem.

> Alexander Barvinok, *Matrices with prescribed row and column sums*,
> Linear Algebra and its Applications, Volume 436, Issue 4, 2012, Pages 820-844, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2010.11.019

There are no formulas given, only complicated asymptotic results. Therefore, I do not expect your question to have any nice solution.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a look through. I shouldn't be surprised at this point running into these sorts of roadblocks with graphs, but those results might still be handy.

Comment: Yeah, I took a whole class using a small book by Richard Stanley about this question, with just the case $m=n$ and all the $x_i,y_i$ equal. It used horological algebra and other commutative algebra to get some kind of result, I don’t even remember if it got a complete result. But restricting to $2$ boxes (or equivalently, $2$ colors and $n$ boxes) is doable.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Speaking of Stanley, I believe that the symmetric functions section Enumerative Combinatorics vol. 2 mentions that the number of $\Bbb N$-matrices with row sums $\lambda$ and column sums $\mu$ is the coefficient of $m_\mu$ when $h_\lambda$ is expanded into the monomial basis. Perhaps this perspective leads to an effective algorithm to compute the number of such matrices?

Comment: I’m not sure how much good it does. In the above case with $3$ boxes holding $2$,$2$, and $1$ balls, it is the coefficient of $x^2y^2z$ of $$(x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xyz+yz)^2(x+y+z).$$ But I doubt that gives us a useful formula in a more general case. @MikeEarnest. But I’m not sure I’ve ever scanned through, much less read, volume 2 of Stanley. (The course I took with the Stanley book was taught by the man himself, FWIW, way back in the late 80s. The other cool participant in the seminar was Percy Diaconus, shortly after he published his shuffle proof. Well, that was cool to this bridge player.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is equivalent to enumerating the number of ways of selecting two balls for the smaller box.  This follows, since once the smaller box is filled, the remaining balls are forced into the larger box.

Either the two balls in the smaller box are the same color, or they are not.

$\underline{\text{Case 1: The two balls in the smaller box are the same color}}.$ 
There are $\binom{2}{1}$ ways of choosing this color.

$\underline{\text{Case 2: The two balls in the smaller box are not the same color}}.$ 
Of the $(3)$ colors to choose from, for the smaller box, there are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of choosing two colors out of three.

Final computation: $\displaystyle \binom{2}{1} + \binom{3}{2}.$

Comment: Very clear +1 !